# iOS objective c socket p2p connection with peers behind NAT

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nat, stun

I have to implement socket communication in iOS (Objective-C) between two peers located behind NAT (in different networks). Are there any techniques allowing me to achieve this? Basically I 'm looking for some STUN, TURN implementation, that would allow me find out external IP/Port address.

Thanks in advance,
Leonid

Comment: Looks like I found something https://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/

Comment: unfortunatelly that library is only for mac os

Comment: Just started investigation in similar question, and found this app: http://www.linphone.org/. You could look through it's source code, maybe you'll find out answer to your question.

Comment: Have you tried Hole Punching?

Comment: One option is to have both peer connect to a server. Your server code is then responsible for relaying data between the 2 peers